# An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to map the path '/'

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-config, relative-path

I get An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to map the path '/'. when i try to run following line to get path of web.config

```
Configuration config =System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
```

I am running Windows 7 , Visual studio 2010 and .net framework 4.0 . Now i know that this issue is resolved by running visual studio as administrator and i have run same code numerous times before doing run as administrator but today running as administrator is not resolving the issue as well . I have run same code on laptops of my team mates and code works perfectly and when i run that code on my laptop it does not work .

I have tried everything , is there a way i can give an absolute path somehow to make it work temporarily and can my windows be an issue because it is in bad condition lately . Kindly help as it is wasting a lot of my time

Comment: Every time I've had "Failed to map the path" it's been permissions issues. That would also explain why it would work (until today?) when running as an Administrator. I'd make sure you have read/write on all the source code, and the directories.

Comment: Few files have a lock on them . I will try making them writeable

Comment: try open your vs administrator

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem and initially I was using the same workaround of launching Visual Studio as administrator.

Finally I tried to do some tests and got this: If you create a filemap for the web.config the application loads the config without administrator privileges.

I have used the example from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.openmappedwebconfiguration(v=vs.110).aspx but with some modifications:

```
    public static Configuration GetConfiguration()
    {
        if (HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath == "/")
            return WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/web.config");

        WebConfigurationFileMap fileMap = CreateFileMap(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath);
        // Get the Configuration object for the mapped virtual directory.
        return WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration(fileMap, HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath);
    }

    private static WebConfigurationFileMap CreateFileMap(string applicationVirtualPath)
    {

        WebConfigurationFileMap fileMap =
               new WebConfigurationFileMap();

        // Get he physical directory where this app runs. 
        // We'll use it to map the virtual directories 
        // defined next.  
        string physDir = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;

        // Create a VirtualDirectoryMapping object to use 
        // as the root directory for the virtual directory 
        // named config.  
        // Note: you must assure that you have a physical subdirectory 
        // named config in the curremt physical directory where this 
        // application runs.
        VirtualDirectoryMapping vDirMap =
            new VirtualDirectoryMapping(physDir, true);

        // Add vDirMap to the VirtualDirectories collection  
        // assigning to it the virtual directory name.
        fileMap.VirtualDirectories.Add(applicationVirtualPath, vDirMap);

        // Create a VirtualDirectoryMapping object to use 
        // as the default directory for all the virtual  
        // directories.
        VirtualDirectoryMapping vDirMapBase =
            new VirtualDirectoryMapping(physDir, true, "web.config");

        // Add it to the virtual directory mapping collection.
        fileMap.VirtualDirectories.Add("/", vDirMapBase);

        // Return the mapping. 
        return fileMap;
    }
```

I think this is not a very cool fix, but it works and can be enclosed in a #if DEBUG section.

With these I am deducing that when you launch Visual Studio web development server having set the Virtual Path setting to some like "/MyApplication", if it has been launched with administrator privileges it creates some mappings it does not create when not having the privileges. It is only an hypothesis that I could not verify.

I hope this will help others!

Answer (score 1):

To get the location of the config file you can do the following:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile
```

If you want a reference to the file then you could do:

```
ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

Comment: will it return file as a configuration file ? or it will return path ?

Comment: @ffayyaz: its return full physical path of web.config file

Answer (score 1):

try this one, which has always worked for me:

```
Configuration config 
     =System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/");
```

OR even this one:

```
Configuration config 
         =System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("./");
```

Make sure you have a reference to `System.Configuration.dll` assembly.

It seems like you are trying to open the Web.Config Configuartion file from application, So you may also use below one. What it means is you don't need to open the file anyway. Check [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151434.aspx).

```
var section = WebconfigurationManager.GetSection("Section_Name");
```